# Is it possible to dynamically change the URL from where the chunks of lazy-loaded modules are loaded in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, module, routes, lazy-loading, ngroute

I am developing an Angular 6 application, but because of deployment reasons, I cannot load the chunks generated by the lazy-loaded modules of my application from the URL that (by now) is assigned to them.
When I navigate to the lazy-loaded module, the application requires the chunk "4.js" from `my_application_base_href/4.js`, but this is not gonna work **in my deployment case**.

I have tried exploring the router events and investigated about lazy loading but this seems to be a much deeper mechanism in the angular routing. Maybe it is related to webpack configuration somehow.

I have found the loading of the chunks is performed by the angular-router-loader, which is configured in the webpack configuration. However, it does not seem that there is any configuration option to dynamically modify the URL, ¿maybe some alternative loader would provide this?

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: './reservar/reservar.module#ReservarModule', /* This generates the problems after building */
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I was wondering if any way exists to change the URL from where this modules are loaded in a dynamic way. The idea would be to take a variable from `window` (e.g. `window.baseUrl`), and ensure Angular will load the chunks from that URL and not the original one.
Some way to manipulate the URL myself before the load is called would be enough.